# JavaBDD eliminating (and simplifying BDD) when a variable value is know (from the diagram)

Tags: java, binary-decision-diagram

I am new to binary decision diagrams (BDD) and I am stuck when I try to simplify/recalculate a BDD after the value of a variable is known.

The programming language is Java and the BDD package used is JavaBDD.

### Code follows.

```
import net.sf.javabdd.BDD;
import net.sf.javabdd.BDDFactory;

public class run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        print("A program to familize myself with BDD");
        runSimplifyBDD();
        print("Program ended");

    }

    private static void runSimplifyBDD() {
        BDDFactory B;
        B = BDDFactory.init(1000, 1000);
        B.setVarNum(8);
        BDD v1 = B.nithVar(1);
        BDD v2 = B.ithVar(2);
        BDD v3 = B.ithVar(3);
        BDD v4 = B.ithVar(4);
        BDD v5 = B.ithVar(5);
        BDD v6 = B.ithVar(6);
        BDD v7 = B.ithVar(7);

        BDD a = v1.xor(v2).not();
        BDD b = v2.xor(v3).not();
        BDD c = (a.xor(b)).not();
        BDD d = v4.xor(v5).not().xor(v6);
        BDD e = v6.xor(v7).not();
        BDD f = d.xor(e).not();

        BDD g = c.xor(f);

        g.printDot(); //first graph diagram
        /* At this point
         * let say we know the BDD variable v1 = One (true)
         * What is the code that should be inserted to simplify the BDD 
         * so that second graph is like the attached image
         */

        g.printDot(); //second graph diagram

    }

    private static void print(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);

    }

}
```

At the comment what is the code that should be inserted so that int second diagram the variable v1 is eliminated like in the images.

[image: Graph1]
[image: Graph2]

The graphviz tool (ver 1.02) was used to generate the images by copy/paste of the output from `g.printDot();`

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with JavaBDD, but with many other BDD packages. 
What you need is the compose function:
http://javabdd.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/javabdd/BDDFactoryIntImpl.IntBDD.html#compose%28net.sf.javabdd.BDD,%20int%29

```
public BDD compose(BDD g,
                   int var)
```

This replaces the variable var for the expression g. 
In your case the variable is v1, and the expression is True.
So

```
h = g.compose(One,1);
```

should do what you want.
(I am not sure what the name for the constant True BDD in JavaBDD is, 
I assumed One).

Comment: do you know what difference it make if I use compose function instead of restrict? http://javabdd.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/javabdd/BDD.html#restrict(net.sf.javabdd.BDD)

Comment: `compose` is the right function to use, because it substitutes the given value for the indicated variable. `restrict` attempts to find a Boolean function whose BDD is small, assuming as care set the given BDD. The document [Binary Decision Diagrams](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/labs/vlsicad/ece667/reading/somenzi99bdd.pdf) by Fabio Somenzi describes these (in particular, see Sec. 5.4.2 "The Restrict Operator").

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution is to use restrict function as below.

```
   //..............omitted lines..........

            g.printDot(); //first graph diagram
            /* At this point
             * let say we know the BDD variable v1 = One (true)
             * What is the code that should be inserted to simplify the BDD 
             * so that second graph is like the attached image
             */

            g.restrictWith(v1); //added line - use 'g.restrictWith(v1.not());' for negative restriction

            g.printDot(); //second graph diagram
```

//..............omitted lines................

Thanks again,
Steve